# Compiling GNU C into C89

Tags: c, gcc, c89

I have a project where the target will probably be an embedded system of some type with a compiler that's probably C89 or equivalent. However, I would like to use the GCC extensions from GNU C.

Is there a way to tell GCC to compile to C89? Maybe some assembly/disassembly process?

Comment: Ok, but the gnu extensions probably won't work on Proprietary EmbedCo's compiler

Comment: Also, I know // comments work, not sure if that's an extension

Comment: It's unclear why you can't just use GCC to cross-compile for your target rather than using some ancient C89 compiler.

Comment: If you used GNU extensions and suddenly needs to compile everything in a standard C compiler, tough luck. GNU extensions are non-portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling to C89 is not the same the same as gcc with extensions, unfortunately. They are in fact mutually exclusive.

You need to decide for sure which you want for your project, and then look at the -std=c89 (and possibly -pedantic) options to gcc if you really want to stick to C89. If you want GNU extensions, look at the gcc docs, there is a fairly extensive set of options for the -std= argument.

There are also a number of gcc cross-compilers in existence, take a look at those and see if they fit your embedded target platform, you may have an easier path available.

Comment: I see. I was thinking that maybe GCC acted like the Glasgow Haskell compiler and desugared it's extended language into something compatible with the standard before compiling and that I could get at that

Comment: @k_g Extensions to the C language mostly really extend the language in that they make previously impossible things possible. There isn't really a way to turn most of them into standard C code.

Comment: That might be nice, but I am not aware of any such handholding in gcc. If you have something working in gcc right now, I think your best bet is probably a gcc cross-compiler for your target.

Comment: But this answer works. I'll look into cross compiling because I really don't want to lose psuedo closures

Comment: @k_g I think most GHC extensions can't be desugared into vanilla Haskell either (case in point: Template Haskell). You're not thinking of the desugaring into the Core language (which isn't Haskell)?

Comment: Oh, I thought core was a subset of Haskell. Oops

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about GCC 5 and higher, but before the *default* was actually C89 with GNU extensions.

If you want to be explicit use the `-std` flag, like `-std=gnu89`.

See [Options Controlling C Dialect](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) in the online manual.

---

If you want to use GNU extensions, then you must use a compiler that actually support them, like GCC. If you don't want to use GNU extensions then you can use any compliant compiler.

Also note that GCC is *very* portable. While the later versions might not support your target platform, there are probably earlier versions that does.

Comment: I think OP's objective is to automatically translate from some version of C with GNU extensions to C89 without GNU extensions.

Comment: This won't be particularly helpful given that the gnu extensions are gcc specific anyway. I would like to be able to write gnu C and compile using a c89 compiler.

Comment: @k_g Have you tried building a GCC *cross-compiler* for your target platform? Then you *can* use the GNU extensions. Otherwise you can't. It's that simple. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Well, in gcc 5 "The default mode for C is now -std=gnu11 instead of -std=gnu89."

Comment: Downvoting because this is not answering OPs question.